# quick function to replace ' with \' in php

Tags: php

Having a mental block....

I know this is so easy.... but nothing is going my way today!

Can anyone help me with a quick function to search a string and escape all apostrophes in php. Thanks.

Comment: if you are escaping for db statements use the appropriate `*_real_escape_string` functions instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**addslashes**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Comment: as long as he is aware this will also add slashes to " and \

Comment: True - also NUL bytes.  You would usually want to escape those as well in situations where you are escaping quotes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
$changed_string = str_replace("'","\\'",$input_string)
```

You can also make use of the library function [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php). Remember it will add slashes in front of single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$str = ...
$str = str_replace("'", "\\'", $str);
```