# How to add slashes for quotes in a string using PHP?

Tags: php, html, escaping, backslash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [quick function to replace ' with \' in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421491/quick-function-to-replace-with-in-php)
>   [Is there a PHP function that only adds slashes to double quotes NOT single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611468/is-there-a-php-function-that-only-adds-slashes-to-double-quotes-not-single-quotes)

I have for example:

```
$one = 'put "returns" between "paragraphs"';

$two = '"linebreak" add 2 spaces "at end"';
```

How can I convert this for:

```
$one = 'put \"returns\" between \"paragraphs\"';

$two = '\"linebreak\" add 2 spaces \"at end\"';
```

Comment: try entering your question title in google

Comment: Basic question...try Google next time. For now, look at the addslashes method of PHP

Comment: `addslashes` is not correct, it will replace more. So everybody who feels eager to close because of that (the only suggested duplicate so far), might have googled too quickly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you're looking for is either `str_replace` or [`addcslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php):

```
$one = 'put "returns" between "paragraphs"';

$slashed = addcslashes($one, '"');

echo $slashed;
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/C176qH9z).

Answer (score 6):

```
$one = str_replace('"', '\"', $one);
```

Answer (score 5):

To add the slashes, use

```
$one = addslashes($one);
```

Or to remove

```
$one = stripslashes($one);
```